# CRM web resource attachment retrieve with C#

Tags: html, dynamics-crm

I am currently requested by client to create a function in CRM which allow them to upload attachment to a record. Then upload the attachment to SFTP.

I would like to know how do i retrieve the attachment from the html web  resource i created for uploading the attachment. The Below is my html scripts for the upload button.

```
<html><head>  
<style>  
.button {  
    background-color: 00bfff;  
    border: none;  
    color: white;  
    text-align: center;  
    text-decoration: none;  
    display: inline-block;  
    font-size: 10px;  
    cursor: pointer;  
    border-radius: 6px;  
}  
</style>  
<script>  
function Addattachment()  
{  
var entityETC=10086; 
var entityID =window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();  
parent.Mscrm.RibbonActions.addFileToRecord(1, entityID)  
}  
</script>  
<meta charset="utf-8"><meta><style type="text/css">P { margin: 0; }</style><meta><style type="text/css">P { margin: 0; }</style></head>  
<body onfocusout="parent.setEmailRange();" style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">  
<button class="button" onclick="Addattachment()">Attach</button>  
</body></html>
```

just for your reference. this quetion might extend to other questions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-webapi/retrieverecord

Answer (score 0):

I get the impression that you are following [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/adding-custom-html-button-for-attachment/). 
As the author notes, the `addFileToRecord` method is unsupported.
Please also note that entity type code (ETC) of custom entities can differ between systems, so if you migrate this code from say a DEV org to a PROD org, you may need to update the ETC in the code.

Dynamics 365 stores user attachments on the Annotation entity (a.k.a. "notes"). As @jasonscript points out, you'll need to retrieve the note that just got attached. However the `retrieveRecord` API method requires you to know the ID of the record you want to retrieve. Unless the `addFileToRecord` method returns the ID of the attached annotation (which it does not appear to), you'll need to use [`retrieveMultipleRecords`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-webapi/retrievemultiplerecords), with the proper filter.

Jason Lattimer's [CRMRESTBuilder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder) can help you build that filter.

After retrieving the attachment you should be able to use JavaScript to post the attachment to SFTP. (While I have never done SFTP from within a D365 web resource, I don't believe there's anything stopping you.)

However, going back to the title of your question, you indicate that you're looking to upload the attachment via C#. If your system is on-premise, you can register your plugin outside the sandbox - i.e. without protocol restrictions. If it's online, your plugins will be registered in the [sandbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/plugin-isolation-trusts-statistics), which limits their outside access protocols to HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: Yes, i was trying to use the script from that article.